# To display a button only for the last Flipper image in Viewflipper

Tags: java, android, viewflipper

In my app i have one Viewflipper in which four images will be loaded from array in programmatically.
But only for the Last flipper image i need to display a go button.

```
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/view_flipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ViewFlipper>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/gotoapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="go"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

In java:

```
int gallery_grid_Images[]={R.drawable.splash1,R.drawable.splash2,R.drawable.splash3,R.drawable.splash4};
mViewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.view_flipper);
for(int i=0;i<gallery_grid_Images.length;i++)
    {
        setFlipperImage(gallery_grid_Images[i]);
    }
```

For setflipperImage() method:

```
     private void setFlipperImage(int res) {
       ImageView image = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
       image.setBackgroundResource(res);
       mViewFlipper.addView(image);
     }
```

So please help me how to visible/show the "Go" button for `only last flipper image(4th image)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to get the current Child position:

```
flipper.getDisplayedChild();
```

And this to set child number to view:

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(4);
```

Add an animation listener to the animation object you set as the viewflipper's 'IN' animation. Overide the listeners onAnimationEnd method, and inside that method check

```
 if(flipper.getDisplayedChild() == 4)
      visible your GO Button
     else 
      hide your button
```

Comment: Tried with the code in animation listener works fine but after clicking next or prevs button the go button should hide but its showing.

Comment: you can add else condition and hide button. check my updated answer

Comment: In animation end listener, tried by hiding the button but when i swipe its sliding the image can u tell me how to stop when i slide right for the last image and when i slide left for the first image.

Comment: what you want to stop?? sliding??

Comment: Currently what happen when you tried for left sliding on first image??

Comment: When i slide the left for first image it should not show the last image but its showing last flipper image. But the prevs button is hiding thats working fine.

Comment: i tried with some code its working fine stopped swiping for both last and first image thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Look into this example: it explains everything: http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

Answer (score 2):

Before you set an Animation to your ViewFlipper by `mViewFlipper.setInAnimation`, add the listener to it and override its `onAnimationEnd` callback. There, you check which view is currently displaying on your ViewFlipper and make the button visible, if it is the last one.

```
// load an animation for mViewFlipper, res/anim folder must contain it
mFlipperAnimIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.view_flipper_in);

// set up the listener
mFlipperAnimIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // here, if you reach last image, change visibility of your button
        if (mViewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == mViewFlipper.getChildCount() - 1) {
            buttonGoToApp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            buttonGoToApp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // leave other callbacks blank unless you want some other actions caused by animation
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) { }
});

// finally, set up IN animation for your ViewFlipper
mViewFlipper.setInAnimation(mFlipperAnimIn);
```

Comment: I tried this but when i click next or back it should hide the go button but its showing all the time once after visible.

Comment: No problem, just add `else` statement to `onAnimationEnd` where you will hide the button